# Ruby on Rails - Ruby code in view file gets printed

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

I have a Rails 3 project in Aptana Studio 3 with a *html.erb* view file containing the following code:

```
<% if @books.blank? %>
<p>
    There are not any books currently in the system.
</p>
<% else %>
<p>
    These are the current books in our system
</p>
<ul id="books">
    <% @books.each do |c| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<p>
    <%= link_to "Add new Book", {:action => 'new' }%>
</p>
```

Then in the embedded terminal, I run `rails server`, click the "Run with Firefox Server" button in Aptana which opens the application with firefox, and directs me to this link: *http://127.0.0.1:8020/library/app/views/book/book.html.erb*

The problem is that I get this output:

```
<% if @books.blank? %>

There are not any books currently in the system.
<% else %>

These are the current books in our system

    <% @books.each do |c| %>
    <%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%>
    <% end %> 

<% end %>

<%= link_to "Add new Book", {:action => 'new' }%>
```

Seems like the ruby code isn't getting evaluated but rather printed, however the syntax looks alright to me... Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Aptana doesn't open the right page. If you're just using the default server, then you probably want to open `localhost:3000`.

Some more info: look at the url, it's just the path to a file, not the url for the books index.

Your file path (`http://127.0.0.1:8020/library/app/views/book/book.html.erb`) also seems strange...

First, the `book` folder name should be plural (`app/views/books`). And second, your view code seems like it's the books index page, so it probably should be in `app/views/books/index.html.erb`.

Comment: Then I get the  standard "Welcome to Rails" home page... But I also noticed this error during the startup: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/library")`. The name of the project is "library" so could that be the problem?

Comment: Delete the index.html file in /public.

Comment: This error now shows up on the page: `No route matches [GET] "/"`

Comment: Just find any tutorial to set up a RoR web application and start over. It seems you just skipped too many steps.

Comment: I agree with @oldergod... Show us your routes file.

Comment: I think I probably should start from scratch, I'm pretty sure I messed up something elsewhere... Thanks for all the suggestions though